# C# RSA signing without ASN.1 encoding

Tags: c#, openssl, rsa, signing

First of all, I need to replicate `echo -n "someUnhashedData" | openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey rsa.key | base64 -w 0` functionality in C# code. I managed to load private key into `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider` and call `SignData`, but the result I'm getting is different from that of `openssl pkeyutl`.

As far as I understand, per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/943972/what-is-the-difference-between-openssl-pkeyutl-sign-and-openssl-rsautl-sign) and [this RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) when `pkeyutl -sign` is called without `-pkeyopt digest:hashFunc` openssl does not bundle data with digest function identifier and skips ASN.1 encoding. This means that raw data is padded and encrypted. [This tool](https://nmichaels.org/rsa.py) seems to confirm that, decrypted signature looks like padded plaintext data.

So how do I do that with C#? All functions from `RSACryptoServiceProvider` require to specify hash algorithm and encode signature before encryption. Is there something I'm missing or will I have to write my own RSA private encryption?

Answer (score 0):

.NET has no inbox API to performing "raw RSA".  If you need that capability to match an existing bug in another RSA consumer you would have to make a new class which P/Invokes down to the system cryptographic libraries (or otherwise provides the functionality you seek)